# При применении Padding к div картинка начинает копироваться и растягиваться

Tags: html, css, веб-сайт

Есть блок div black-block я пытаюсь сделать на фон картинку с отступом верх:низ по 80px, а лево и право по 0, но она вытягивается вниз и начинает копироваться при этом если применяю но репит то копии пропадают но остается пустое место справа на сайте, помогите уже голова кипит, знаю что код должен работать 100% именно в таком виде.

```
        <div class="black-block">
        <div class="conteiner">
            <div class="block-holder">
                <div class="left">
                    <div class="left-title">
                        Отпразднуйте в одном из<br>самых лучших ресторанов.
                    </div>
                    <div class="left-text">
                        Только в нашей студии есть система пригласи друга!
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <div class="right-button">
                        <a class="right-btn" href="#">БРОНИРОВАНИЕ</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Вот ксс

    .black-block {
    background-image: url(black-bg.png);
    padding: 80px 0;
}

.left-title {
    color: #D67E34;
    font-size: 52px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Tinos', serif;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.left-text {
    color: #FFFF;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.right-btn {
    background-color: #FF7400;
    color: #FFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 18px;
    font-weight: 700;

    transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
}

.right-btn:hover {
    background-color: #883e02;
}

.block-holder {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Исходный вид: [image: Исходный вид]

Как выглядит с no-repit: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если хотите растянуть фон, то ознакомьтесь с этим [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), если спозиционировать, то с этим [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position). Логично, что с `no-repeat` она не будет повторяться.